# "Sub or Function not defined" vba

Tags: vba, excel

VBA novice here

When I run my code I receive the error "Sub or Function not defined". This occurs in one of my subroutines. The first line is highlighted in yellow by the debugger.

```
Sub Description(Row As Integer, SheetName As String)

With Worksheet(SheetName)

.Cells(Row, 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)   
.Cells(Row, 2) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)   
.Cells(Row, 3) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)

End With
End Sub
```

This subroutine takes in a number and a string. I want to copy specific descriptions into into another worksheet "SheetName". Here is a piece of the code prior to the subroutine call. The value of "x" is declared outside the loops scope.

```
string_temp = "Sheet2"
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Select
Call Description(x, string_temp)
x= x + 1
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: It should be`Worksheets`, not `worksheet`.

Answer (score 1):

`With Worksheet(SheetName)` should be `With Worksheets(SheetName)`

Also change `Row As Integer` to `Row as Long`, `Integer` is actually marginally slower in `VBA` as the compiler converts it to a Long for processing.